# Connection buffer issue using nbastatR

Tags: r, connection

I am running this package "[nbastatR](https://rdrr.io/github/abresler/nbastatR/)" for getting NBA data. I keep getting either of the two errors when using functions in the package. I am very new to the package and the errors. Does anyone know how to check and set up the correct "connection buffer" for my computer? Thank you!

```
> nba_teams(league = "NBA", join_blg = F)
Error: The size of the connection buffer (131072) was not large enough
to fit a complete line:
  * Increase it by setting `Sys.setenv("VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE")`
```

Another example:

```
> teams_seasons_info(teams = "Brooklyn Nets", seasons = c(1995, 2018), season_types = "Regular Season")
Error: The size of the connection buffer (131072) was not large enough
to fit a complete line:
  * Increase it by setting `Sys.setenv("VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE")`
```

This is the information of my system:

```
> Sys.info()
    sysname         release         version        nodename         machine                        
  "Windows"        "10 x64"   "build 19044"          "XXX"        "x86-64"
```

Comment: try to increase connection buffer size : `Sys.setenv("VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE"= 131072 * 10)`

Comment: Thank you for the response @Basti! How do I know the size I need? I tried multiple much bigger sizes, but it still gives the same error.